# Modificar Map Java

Tags: java, netbeans, map, hashmap

Tengo un problema para modificar un HashMap, Ingreso los datos Rut(como key) y sus valores, pero al querer modificar el key me reemplaza los valores, no se si me doy a entender

Por ejemplo los valores ingresados son Rut: 11, Nombre: aa, Cargo bb, al modificarlo debiera (es lo que quiero hacer) reemplazar el Rut por uno nuevo, ejemplo 12, pero al listar me devuelve '11 - 12' reemplazando los valores Nombre y Cargo por el nuevo Rut

No se si estoy bien en el hecho que se pueda modificar la key y mantener sus valores, o si pueden darme una sugerencia de que modificar (ya que me piden metodo modificar, pero se puede modificar cualquier cosa)

Bueh aqui el codigo https://pastebin.com/ViBsfxwh

```
import java.util.*;

/**
*
* @author Fabio
*/
public class Menu {

HashMap<String, worker> Trabajadores = new HashMap<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void Menu(){
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion;
    String Cargo, Nombre, Rut;

    while(!salir) {      
        System.out.println("Menu Opciones");
        System.out.println("[1] D A T O S   T R A B A J A D O R E S");
        System.out.println("[2] L I S T A R");
        System.out.println("[3] Salir");

        try{
            System.out.println("=== Ingrese Numero de Opcion ===");
            opcion=sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcion){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Eliga que desea H A C E R");
                    System.out.println("[1] A G R E G A R");
                    System.out.println("[2] M O D I F I C A R");
                    System.out.println("[3] E L I M I N A R");
                    opcion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch (opcion){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Introduce el R U T del trabajador:");
                            Rut = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("introduce el N O M B R E de trabajador:");
                            Nombre = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Introduce el C A R G O de trabajador");
                            Cargo = sc.next();
                            guardarTrabajador(Rut, new worker(Nombre, Cargo), Trabajadores);
                            break;


                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("R U T de Trabajador que desea M O D I F I C A R: ");
                            Rut = sc.next();
                            modificaTrabajador(Rut, Trabajadores);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Introduce el R U T del Trabajador que deseas E L I M I N A R: ");
                            Rut = sc.next();
                            eliminaTrabajador(Rut, Trabajadores);
                            break;


                        default:
                            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    mostrarTrabajador(Trabajadores);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Usted a decidido salir1");
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion debe ser entre 1 y 5");

        }

        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Debe introducir un numero");
            sc.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Fin del menu");
}

public static void guardarTrabajador(String Rut, worker worker, HashMap 
<String,worker> Trabajadores){
if (Trabajadores.containsKey(Rut)) {
    System.out.println("No es posible agregar este R U T. El código esta repetido.");
} else {
    Trabajadores.put(Rut, worker);              
    }
}    

public static void modificaTrabajador(String Rut, HashMap Trabajadores){/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
if (Trabajadores.containsKey(Rut)) {
    System.out.println("Nuevo R U T de Trabajador: ");
    Trabajadores.put(Rut, sc.next());            
 } else {
    System.out.println("No hay trabajadores con este R U T");  
     }
  }

 public static void mostrarTrabajador(HashMap<String, worker> Trabajadores) {
String search;
Iterator<String> work = Trabajadores.keySet().iterator();
System.out.println("Los trabajadores registrados son: ");
while(work.hasNext()){
    search = work.next();
    System.out.println(search + " - " + Trabajadores.get(search));
    }        
}  

public static void eliminaTrabajador(String Rut, HashMap<String,worker> Trabajadores) {
if (Trabajadores.containsKey(Rut)) {
    Trabajadores.remove(Rut);
 } else {
    System.out.println("No hay trabajadores con este R U T");  
    }      
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que está modificando el valor que tiene la clave `Rut` , por la entrada del `scanner`

```
Trabajadores.put(Rut, sc.next());
//               11  ,  12
```

Es por eso que la clave no se modifica *(en dicha linea)*  , por eso es que obtiene los resultados de `11 - 12` , si desea modificar no solo el valor si no la clave, la opción sería remover primero el valor con la clave a modificar , para luego añadir una nueva clave y valor ,

> ya que según la implementación de la clase `HashMap` , el atributo
>   `key` está declarado como  `final K key;` por lo cuál no puede
>   ser sobreescrita.

```
public static void modificaTrabajador(String Rut, HashMap Trabajadores){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (Trabajadores.containsKey(Rut)) {

        System.out.println("Nuevo R U T de Trabajador: ");
        String rutx = sc.next();
        // Removemos del HashMap la antigua clave - valor
        Trabajadores.remove(Rut);
        System.out.println("Nuevo Nombre de Trabajador: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Nuevo Cargo de Trabajador: ");
        String cargo = sc.next();
        //Agregamos Nuevo Elemento con clave rutx
        Trabajadores.put(rutx, new worker(name,cargo) );            
     } else {
        System.out.println("No hay trabajadores con este R U T");  
     }
}
```

El escenario en este ejemplo es que las claves principales por lo general no se modifican, el RUT es uno de ellos, por lo cuál no tendría razón para requerir la nueva clave , solo los nuevos valores para `nombre` y `cargo`.

```
if (Trabajadores.containsKey(Rut)) {
    System.out.println("Nuevo Nombre de Trabajador: ");
    String name = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Nuevo Cargo de Trabajador: ");
    String cargo = sc.next();
    //Agregamos  Elemento con clave Rut(Sin modificarla)
    Trabajadores.put(Rut, new worker(name,cargo) );            
 }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias estimado! Tu respuesta me ayudo a entender de manera correcta mi error y lo que debía hacer, hasta me causo gracia que fuera asi de "simple" jaja no te imaginas cuanto te lo agradezco

Comment: @iFabio me alegra que le haya ayudado mi respuesta , Saludos.